Elsa Workflow 3 simple workflow for chatbox
Im new with Elsa Workflow 3 and I was reading about all the incredible and great stuff it supports.
I just want to create a simple workflow for a chatbot where I can have a flow like this:

User reply if want to get enrolled or not (YES or NO)
If NO then workflow needs to return a string message "Thanks for participating"
If YES then workflow need to return string message "When do you want to get enrolled? 1) Today 2) Tomorow 3) Next week
Depending on each option a different string message is responded
Then other question is generated "Please select a route" (Here i can have 10 options)
If Other option is selected then string message is sent "Please write the route"

And so on.
So is simple but I'm kind of lost. Each user might be in a differnet stage of the workflow so it has to resume the workflow where he left it.
Can someone help me or guide me on how to create this please.
